# Filter button properties set for right click

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to give the filter button a right click function that when I right click it, it will clear all the grid criteria.

```
        setFilterOnKeypress(false);
        setFilterByCell(true);
        setFilterButtonPrompt("Left click to filter, right click to clear all texts.");
        Button button = new Button();
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                if (event.isRightButtonDown())
                {
                    SC.warn("right clicked");
                    clearCriteria();
                }
            }
        });
        setFilterButtonProperties(button);
```

This is not working, any ideas on why it isnt working?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434318/right-click-in-gwt/

Comment: Have you tried using a custom button that implements `ContextMenuHandler` and sinks `addDomHandler(this, ContextMenuEvent.getType());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Keep the functionality separate. There is no meaning of mixing two different tasks on the same button. Think from the end user's perspective.*

Read more on your another post [Pass a handler to filter button property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912837/pass-a-handler-to-filter-button-property?answertab=votes#tab-top) that is some what asked in the same context.